# When i create a hadoop conf object, is code executed in Hadoop environment, even if it is a standalone Java Code?

Tags: java, hadoop, compression, hadoop2

I need to understand that if i use Hadoop conf object in my code, is all the code executed in the Hadoop environment or in the normal environment , even if there are no hadoop operations in my code. I have written a stand alone java module and doing normal operations but I need Hadoop conf object to apply in-built Hadoop compression on the data and store the data in normal location only.

I run the jar as hadoop jar jar_name

Answer (score 0):

Code with just hadoop jar in its classpath does not execute on a Hadoop environment (which can be cluster, pseudo-distributed or local); even if you have a cluster and have provided proper config (and you can use an Empty config object).
The points of entry to hadoop environment are HDFS operations and running jobs.